# Django y Oracle

Tags: django, oracle

Tengo un proyecto django que necesito conectar a una base de datos oracle

Cuando utilizo sqlite3 que trae por defecto con el siguiente string:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

La aplicacion funciona sin problemas pero cuando conecto con oracle con el siguiente string:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DBARS_PROD',
        'USER': 'userhere',
        'PASSWORD': 'passhere',


        }
}
```

django me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 62, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 332, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 303, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 289, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Pero si corro el comando python manage.py test para probar la coneccion me devuleve que todo esta correcto:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Creating test user...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test user...
Destroying test database tables...
```

Parece que cuando django consulta oracle este le devuelve unicode y no strings. o alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Las instrucciones dicen que _forzosamente_ debes incluir `HOST` y `PORT` aunque sean cadenas vacías. Mira: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#id14

Comment: Si, pero estoy usando un tnsname.ora por lo tanto no es necesario, ** if you don’t use a tnsnames.ora**, ademas con el python manage.py test demuestra que si conecto con la base de datos escribio y guardo al igual que elimino data, parece ser que la base de datos envia unicode y django necesita strings